# Selecting interface on Android things Rpi3

Tags: networking, android-things

I would like to send data to my server from a Raspberry.

The Raspberry is connected by Wi-Fi to a network, and by Ethernet to my server.

When I try to ping my server (at 198.168.1.30) I must specify the interface :

`ping -I eth0 198.168.1.30` otherwise, I have an error message : `Network unreachable.`

In my Android Things App, I have the same error. I think I have to "say" to my raspberry to send the request on eth0.

Is it possible to specify on which interface we want to contact an address on Android Things App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem : The OS, Android things, cannot hanlde two interfaces at the same time. The problem is not comming from the app.

Android Things needs to get its IP address from a DHCP server : you can try to assign a static address with `ifconfig` conmmand, but Android Things won't use the interface anyway.
Android will use : the first interface connected who had its IP through a DHCP service. If both Ethernet and Wi-Fi are available at boot, Wi-Fi gets the priority.
Lastly, if you connect Wi-Fi (with DHCP) after Ethernet, the Android Things device will use the Wi-Fi but only for answering ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you want to use the [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). It has a method called [`requestNetwork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest, android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) which lets you select the type of network you want based on a [`NetworkRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.html) object which lets you filter available interfaces based on properties like [`TRANSPORT_ETHERNET`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#TRANSPORT_ETHERNET).

You will get a callback with your [`Network`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html) object, which you can then use to [create a `URLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)). You will probably get back an [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (or an [`HttpsURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)) and then you can follow the code snippets there to see how to make a basic request to a server.

Comment: Thank you !
By the way, don't you know how to make an Android Thing answer to ping requests please ?

Comment: I don't know for `ping`. It does not connect over normal `ssh`.

Comment: I used `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();` and displayed the result in my app log, to know more about the current network.
It appears that my ActiveNetwork is :


`[type: Ethernet[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: b8:27:eb:b3:07:30, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]`


Do I need to use requestNetwork() ?

Comment: I'm sorry to unpick your answer but it doesn't change anything to use `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork`. Moreover, I need to use UDP and `URLConnection` works only with `HTTP`

Comment: There's both `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection` for either protocol type.

Comment: `HTTP` and `HTTPS` both work with `TCP` . If I set an `HTTP` or `HTTPS` connection it won't be a `UDP` connection.   I found that I can create a `DatagramSocket` specifying an `InetSocketAddress(String hostname, int port);` I will try to make it match my interface with the same IP as `hostname`. If it works I'll update this question